# CCSpriteFrame's gone when Android device go into sleep

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2d-x and I'm satisfied using this awesome stuff.

I'm using CCSpriteFrameCache with some plist files. but When I press the sleep button of my Android device and back to game again, It seems like loading all sprite frame again!! I noticed because It needs 3~4 seconds to back to game from sleep mode. and It works fine if I don't use CCSpriteFrameCache. and It's definately fine when I try on iPhone.

and I noticed It have been as a issue at the cocos2d-x forum.

any helps? I don't think people would understand 3~4 seconds delay every single time when they back to game from sleep mode.

Thanks. God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using pvr.ccz as texture file and what happens to you sounds like texture not been cached on android devices.

If this is the case, this is a known bug and the fix is already applied on the new version.

There are 2 way to fix the problem:

1. Update your cocos2d-x source and recompile it (any version higher than 0.12.0)
2. Manually apply the fix by yourself according to this page: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/10/topics/7670